# Loose coupling : Can we use Interfaces when we need cloneables params?

Tags: java, interface, clone, loose-coupling, pmd

As I was advised by [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/), I want to reduce coopling by using interfaces instead of implementation ...

In this case, knowing that I need a cloneable param, can I overcome the [clone Dilemma](http://www.artima.com/intv/issues3.html) (no `clone()` method in the `Cloneable` interface) ??

```
public MyConstructor(ArrayList<E> myParam) {
    this.myAttribute = (ArrayList<E>) myParam.clone();
}
```

Comment: @Allain : Hello I'm curious to know what do you edited in this question ? I'm quite new to SO and I'm not familiar with this concept of editing questions ...

Comment: Click on the phrase `edited ... ago` to see the revision history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to clone that way; I'd do it like this:

```
public MyConstructor(List<E> myParam) 
{
    this.myAttribute = new ArrayList<E>(myParam);
}
```

Comment: Note that this produces an ArrayList that will allocate enough space for 110% the size of the provided List. So, it's not exactly a clone.

Comment: True, but I think it serves the purpose.

Comment: @duffymo & Allain : thx !! it perfectly serve my purpose !!! and it's also interesting to know that it's not really a clone ...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know PMD well, but this would be a shallow copy, instead of deep copy.